# Stereoselectivity solvolysis of cyclohexenyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

When a functionalized cyclohexenyl halide undergoes $\ce{S_{N}1}$, does a racemic product form (due to ring flipping) ?

Comment: The term ‘functionalized cyclohexenyl halide’ is ambiguous. Could you name one example?

Comment: The specific type of functionalization is not very important; I would be primarily interested to know the behaviour of the unfunctionalized molecule and secondarily how e.g. alkyl or hydroxy functionalization affects that.